# Specify LDAP group search attributes in Jetty LdapLoginModule

Tags: java, ldap, jetty, jaas

When using JAAS, is there any way to specify the attributes returned by the role (group) search query?

The group returned has about 100k entries in the `uniqueMember` attribute which is saturating the link between the app server and OpenLDAP. Since the query only needs the `cn` attribute, I'd like to tell the container to only request that when performing the search.

Currently, the query does not set any attributes to be returned, which returns all of them.

The DEV (Jetty) `java.security.auth.login.config` looks like this

```
devldap {
   org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule required
   debug="true"
   contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
   hostname="ldap-dev.example.com"
   port="389"
   bindDn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
   bindPassword="xxxx"
   authenticationMethod="simple"
   forceBindingLogin="true"
   userBaseDn="ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"
   userRdnAttribute="uid"
   userIdAttribute="uid"
   userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
   userObjectClass="inetOrgPerson"
   roleBaseDn="ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
   roleNameAttribute="cn"
   roleMemberAttribute="uniqueMember"
   roleObjectClass="groupOfUniqueNames";
   };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something seriously wrong there. It shouldn't be returning the group entry attributes at all, only the CN.

This looks like a *major* bug in [org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/7.1.0.RC0/jetty-all-7.1.0.RC0-sources.jar!/org/eclipse/jetty/plus/jaas/spi/LdapLoginModule.java?format=ok). It should set the `returningAttributes` property of the `SearchControl` to `new String[]{_roleNameAttribute}` in `getUserRolesByDn()`. You need to report it, and/or patch it yourself.

If you're using OpenLDAP you could consider using the `memberOf` overlay. This gives the user himself an attribute listing all the groups he is a member of. However it isn't retrospective, and as you already clearly have a large directory you would have a job on your hands to populate it from existing groups. The overlay will auto-maintain it once installed, but only for group updates that take place after it's installed.

Comment: fixed in master and will merge to jetty-8 shortly...also for future note bugs on eclipse classes should be opened at bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty

Comment: @jessemcconnell Thanks for the rapid fix but can you explain more why the bug report was in the wrong place?

Comment: org.eclipse classes are all located at eclipse bugzilla...codehaus is just the bits and pieces left over from the migration to eclipse years ago